# Android ClassLoader.getSystemResource

Tags: android

Assuming that I want to use ClassLoader.getSystemResource to read resources

```
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("com/my/some.properties");
```

Where should I place the file some.properties? I get 'null' with such location

```
my.apk/com/my/some.properties
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store some kind of Preferences you should use SharedPreferences. If you want to include some file to read from you should put it in your assets folder and you can read it like this.

```
InputStream input = context.getAssets().open("some.properties");
```

To save data to a file you open it like this.

```
OutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput("some.properties", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and to read the same file you do this.

```
InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("some.properties");
```

This is all covered very well in the [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) topic on the Android Dev Site.

Comment: Actually, I want to understand, if I can use ClassLoader.getSystemResource API in Android, and how. I have some codebase used in both Java and Android enviroments.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to retrieve ClassLoader from some class

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Some.class.getClassLoader();
URL url = classLoader.getResource("com/my/some.properties");
```

The url value is

```
jar:file:/data/app/com.my.apk!/com/my/some.properties
```